# tikzcd incompatible with standalone document class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes, tikz-cd

Trying to generate a `tikz` diagram using `tikzcd` package in a standalone document so that no excess white space and page header/footer is added around the diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=stealth}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=normal]
                    & A \arrow[dl] & \\
  B \arrow[rr] \arrow[ur, "a", dashed, xshift=-2ex, yshift=0.5ex] &                            & C
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=normal]
& A \arrow[dr] & \\
B \arrow[rr] & & C \arrow[ul, "b", swap, dashed, xshift=2ex, yshift=0.5ex]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, only part of the diagram is generated. Changing the document class to 'article' generates the full diagram. Is `tikzcd` not compatible with the 'standalone' class? If so, how can I create a diagram using `tikzcd` without excess white space and page header/footer etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never nest a `tikzpicture` inside another `tikzpicture`; a `tikzcd` is a `tikzpicture`. This thoroughly confuses `standalone` when trying to determine the bounding box.

Also remove the `tikz` option, that tries to make an image out of every `tikzpicture` in the document body.

Edited version, where the `\tikzcdset` instruction has been moved to the preamble so as not to create spurious spaces; the same for `\qquad` moved next to `\end{tikzcd}`. Also `tikz-cd` loads the `arrows` and `arrows.meta` libraries.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=stealth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=normal]
& A \arrow[dl] & \\
B \arrow[rr] \arrow[ur, "a", dashed, xshift=-2ex, yshift=0.5ex] & & C
\end{tikzcd}\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=normal]
& A \arrow[dr] & \\
B \arrow[rr] & & C \arrow[ul, "b", swap, dashed, xshift=2ex, yshift=0.5ex]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!